# Want to save the chat using websockets

Tags: django

I have created an small chatting app using websocket,channels..it works well..now i want to save the chat so that other user can read it later, if he/she is offline at that time.is that possible in django?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Ask a specific question, tell what you have tried to solve it and include relevant code and error messages.

Comment: Yes. Do it inside the consumer if your using channels.